# OpenArgs to Open a subform within a form?

Tags: ms-access, null, command, subform

I have an Access database with a Form that, once the EmployeeID is double-clicked, then it opens another form that contains a subform with employee information. I obtain the EmployeeID from the original form with this code...

```
myID = CInt(Me.OpenArgs)
```

I use this string on my secondary form and the subform contained within, however, it is not picking up the EmployeeID. The main form has this code for the Double-Click event...

```
Private Sub EmployeeID_DblClick(cancel As Integer)
Dim myID As Variant 
myID = Me.EmployeeID

DoCmd.OpenForm "subformEmployeeInfo",,,,,,myID
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_EmployeeInformation",,,,,,myID
End Sub
```

When I step through the code I notice that my ID is there on the OpenForm Command but when it switches to the subform code I get an "Invalid Use of Null" error.

Comment: That is a little confusing. A subform has very little life of its own, it is a child of the parent form and cannot be referred to by name. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need the code in my subform to recognize the EmployeeID from my parent form in order to make the subform work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a subform, you can refer to the Parent OpenArgs,:

```
ID= Me.Parent.OpenArgs
```

These are the OpenArgs of the form on which the subform resides.